# Altura da div no load

Tags: jquery

Como deixar o campo as 2 `divs` com a mesma altura do `#result4` que eu dei um `load`?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $( ".buscascript<?php echo "$row[id]"; ?>" ).click(function() {
        $( "#fechargame" ).show();
        $( "#result4" ).show();
        $( "#result5" ).show();
        $( "#result4" ).load( "busca.php?game=<?php echo "$row[id]"; ?>" );
        var altura = $("#result4").height();
        $( "#publicidade1a" ).height(altura);
        $( "#publicidade" ).height(altura);
    });    
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( ".buscascript<?php echo "$row[id]"; ?>" ).click(function() {
            $( "#fechargame" ).show();
            $( "#result4" ).show();
            $( "#result5" ).show();
            $( "#result4" ).load( "busca.php?game=<?php echo "$row[id]"; ?>", function(){
                var altura = $("#result4").height();
                $( "#publicidade1a" ).height(altura);
                $( "#publicidade" ).height(altura);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

A `function()` que está no `load` é a função que indica o termino do carregamento executado pelo `load`. Nesse momento, você já tem a altura correta para colocar nas tags `publicidade1a` e `publicidade`.

Comment: agora deu certo, vlw!!!

Comment: que bom ... !!!

Comment: Fúlvio, o legal é explicar o *porquê* da solução (no caso, a `function()` do `load`)... O guia [answer] vale uma leitura ;)

Comment: @brasofilo já está explicado ...