# Altura de uma div baseada em outra div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como deixar a div `result777` com o mesmo tamanho da div `publicidade`?

```
<script>
    $( "#result777" ).load(function() {
        if ( $("#publicidade").height() == "390px"){
            var altura3 = $("#publicidade").height();
        }
        else
        {
            var altura3 = "390px";
        }
    });
</script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#result777').slimScroll({
            position: 'right',
            color: '#748392',
            height: altura3,
            width: '310px',
            railVisible: true,
            alwaysVisible: false,
            railColor: '#fff',
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Verifique no slimScroll plugin, como que voce dá update na altura. E chame a função de update dentro do load.

Comment: Manda um fiddle demonstrando o problema, por favor. Assim podemos te ajudar com maior facilidade.

Answer (score 1):

Considerando o que você disse na [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12455/altura-da-div-no-load), parece que te falta o conceito de *operações assíncronas* para você entender o que está ocorrendo. Sempre que você faz uma requisição por ajax (por exemplo, em `$( "#result777" ).load…`), o resultado só chega mais tarde, e as linhas seguintes do código executam imediatamente. Por isso passamos uma função (*callback*) em chamadas ajax, para que seja executada somente quando o resultado chegar.

Dado isso, você tem duas opções:

1. Só iniciar o `slimScroll` depois que o resultado do `load` chegar:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $( "#result777" ).load(function() {
           $('#result777').slimScroll({
               position: 'right',
               color: '#748392',
               height: $("#publicidade").height(),
               width: '310px',
               railVisible: true,
               alwaysVisible: false,
               railColor: '#fff'
           });
       });
   });
   ```
2. Verificar se o plugin slimScroll oferece algum método para redefinir a altura após sua inicialização, como sugerido nos comentários abaixo da pergunta e da resposta do Fúlvio.

Além disso, o `if` no seu primeiro bloco de código não faz nenhum sentido. Ele tenta dizer: se a altura de `$("#publicidade")` for `390`, use `390`, senão use `390`. Ora, se é pra usar `390` sempre, o `if` é desnecessário.

Answer (score 0):

O que eu fiz foi colocar no height do slimScroll o $("#publicidade").height() ...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#result777').slimScroll({
        position: 'right',
        color: '#748392',
        height: $("#publicidade").height(),
        width: '310px',
        railVisible: true,
        alwaysVisible: false,
        railColor: '#fff',
    });
});
</script>
```

Faça os teste e nos fale se resolveu!

Comment: não funciona...

Comment: Tem que verificar mesmo como esse slimScroll configura a altura !!! acredito também que o primeiro trecho ta errado o do load ... não pode ser isso ???

Answer (score 0):

Já resolvi, tive que mudar a altura por css, assim oh:

```
$('.slimScrollDiv').css('height', '500px');
```

o slimscroll usa essa class e dá pra mudar a altura assim

Answer (score 0):

Guarde o valor da div `#publicidade` em uma variável:

```
var tamanho = $('#publicidade').height();
```

Depois atribua esse valor à div `#result777` :

```
$('#result777').css('height' , tamanho);
```